# ¿Cómo verificar si una matriz esta vacia en su totalidad, o en alguna de sus posiciones?

Tags: c, validación, matrices

Tengo una **matriz de chars** de X dimensión por X dimensión, y quisiera saber *si existe alguna forma de verificar si la matriz esta vacía en su totalidad, o en alguna de sus posiciones.*

He intentado comparar cada posición con valores como **NULL** y **"\0"**, pero siempre me arroja un resultado equivocado, ya que hago las pruebas sabiendo que la matriz esta vacía, pero al momento de verificar, o hacer la validación con un IF, este cumple la condición opuesta a la comparación con NULL o "\0", ósea dice que está llena, y supongo que será por basura generada por el compilador.

Supongo que existe alguna forma o alguna solución pero la desconozco, he buscado en diferentes foros, pero todos llegan a la conclusión que en **C** no se puede hacer lo que yo estoy hablando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero habría que definir a qué te refieres con vacía. Si como vacía te refieres a que la localidad de memoria es inexistente, o en otro caso, si la localidad tiene un valor igual a un patrón definido como vacío. Asumo que estamos en el segundo caso dada la comparación que haces con el caracter nulo.

Aún cuando localidad contenga el caracter nulo **'\0'**, ésta seguirá ocupando espacio en memoria. Asegúrate que la comparación la haces elemento por elemento comparando con **'\0'** y no con **"\0"**. El primero denota un caractér, la segunda una cadena

Comment: Ummm si, me hiciste caer en cuenta lo de las comillas, y con respecto a la matriz, hablo de vacia en sus posiciones, pero ya existiendo en memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo de como podrías validar

```
#include <stdio.h>


void main() {

  char matriz[6] = {'s'};
  char matriz2[6] = {};


  matriz[4] = 'e';


  int c = sizeof(matriz) / sizeof(char);
  int c2 = sizeof(matriz2) / sizeof(char);
  int band = 0;

  for(int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {

    if (matriz2[j] != '\0') {

      band = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (! band) {

    printf("La segunda matriz esta vacia\n\n");

  }


  for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {

    if (matriz[i] == '\0') {

      printf("El elemento %d de la matriz es Null\n",i);
    } else {

      printf("El carecter es: %c\n", matriz[i]);

    }
  }

}
```

**Resultado:**

```
La segunda matriz esta vacia

El carecter es: s
El elemento 1 de la matriz es Null
El elemento 2 de la matriz es Null
El elemento 3 de la matriz es Null
El carecter es: e
El elemento 5 de la matriz es Null
```

Comment: Si esta mal la respuesta agredeceria una retro alimentacion

Comment: Si, me aclaraste algunas cosas sobre la verificacion con '\0', no lo tenia muy claro. Gracias